# Syncing data without an Internet connection

Tags: android, networking, ionic3, p2p

I want to build an app *Native*  Android or *hybrid* (ex Ionic Framework).

I need to sync between two devices (Android or IOS) directly when there 
is no Internet connection.

Using **Hotspot** (*Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer*)or **third** Wifi router(*without using Internet for Wifi router)*.

1. So the data synchronized between 2 devices Peer to Peer using
   *hotspot* (nwithout using a PC or a WiFi router)
   Using a direct wireless connection between just these two Android devices
2. so the Data syc from *device* connect to a *Wifi Route* (but without internet)  to *another device*.
   Two devices connect with *equal router Wifi*.

Which it possible  1 or 2?

other ideas will make me very happy

Comment: This would be better served at: https://android.stackexchange.com/. By the way, you could use another communication protocol like bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

In common case - yes, you can. Backup on device1 (e.x., use `Titanium backup`) to SD-card, move it to device2 and restore. But you need both devices to be rooted.

With non-rooted devices, you can use `adb backup` `adb restore` but you need a PC to run `adb` on it.